# Problema para editar CRUD PHP

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

estoy realizando un CRUD con PHP y postgresql, tengo la funcion de crear, listar y borrar ya lista. Me falta la de actualizar.

Hice la funcion de editar la cual me trae los valores del "interesado" y los pone en los input, pero luego en el momento de guardar se me crea como uno nuevo.

code.js

```
this.editar = (id) => {
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("id", id);
    fetch("../controllers/editar.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: form,
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            document.getElementById("id_interesado") = data.id_interesado;
            document.getElementById("nombre").value = data.nombre;
            document.getElementById("apellido").value = data.apellido;
            document.getElementById("telefono").value = data.telefono;
            document.getElementById("email").value = data.email;
            document.getElementById("direccion").value = data.direccion;
            document.getElementById("numero").value = data.numero;
            document.getElementById("localidad").value = data.localidad;
            document.getElementById("dni").value = data.dni;
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

editar.php

```
<?php
require_once "../models/interesado.model.php";
echo json_encode(Interesado::obtenerDatoId($_POST['id']));
```

Dejando la linea: `document.getElementById("id_interesado") = data.id_interesado;` me salta el siguiente error: `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment at code.js:77:26` el cual indica la linea antes dicha

Comment: al parecer no enviás un id en la solicitud de modificación por lo que lo ingresa como uno nuevo.

Comment: @John cuando pongo el getElementById("id_interesado") me tira el error que esta al ultimo

Comment: despues de `.then((data) => {` coloca un   `console.log(data)` asi sabras que trae como respuesta el Json, usa tambien las heramientas de desarrollador que trae el navegador `F12` en el apartado red o network para ver la respuesta a tu llamada fetch

Comment: @John me sale lo siguiente https://imgur.com/a/uVP9ju9

Comment: pero no veo la parte del php donde haces el update... si haces un update no debe por que insertar datos ...

Answer (score 0):

te falta el value de getElementById

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sisi, no habia visto. ahora me tira `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON`